# StoryboardのCustom Classに自作のクラスが表示されない

Tags: objective-c, storyboard

[image: storyboard]

クラスを作成してそれをStoryboardと紐付けしたいのですが、なぜかStoryboardのCustom Classに自作したクラス名が表示されず、紐付けができません。クラス名を打ち込んでも消えてしまいます。そのクラスは現在UIViewControllerを継承しています。以前は今回のような流れでできたのですが......。現在Xcode6を使用しています。...仕様が変わったのでしょうか？初歩的な質問で申し訳ないのですが、宜しくお願いします。

ちなみに下記にstoryboardに紐付けたいクラスのヘッダファイルを記載します。（個人的にここが少し怪しそうな気がしてます......）

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AnimationView : UIViewController

- (id)initWithAnimation:(float)duration fadeOutDelay:(float)fadeOutDelay finishDelay:(float)finishDelay;

@end
```

Comment: これだけでは何とも答えられないので、プロジェクトのスクリーンショット(ソースとIBの画面)を添付したり、コードを追加するなどしてもらえると助かります。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。storyboardのスクリーンショットとコードを載せました。

Comment: インスペクタから選択できなくても、クラス名は直接入力できます。それで動作するか(コードが呼ばれるかどうか)確認してください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

解決することができました。
どうやらstoryboard上をダブルクリックしてUI配置モード（？）になっていたことが原因でした。
もういちどstoryboard上をダブルクリックして遠目の画面にしてCustom Classのclass欄にクラス名を入力すると、正しく入力されました。